# How do i replicate or add more html form fields dynamically with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am currently stuck, i need help adding additional form inputs and labels into a html page using javascript. I am trying to get a number of segments from a user and onclick it creates the additional form fields required. If they provide 3 then it creates an additional 2 form fields with the same variables/selections. I am trying to do this with a for loop in Javascript but have not been successful.

My Html

> ```
>           <h2>New Project</h2>
>           <p>Please enter the information below:</p>
>
>           <label for="project-name">Project Name </label>
>           <input type="text" id = "project-name" class="form-input">
>
>           <label for="segments">Number of Segments </label>
>           <input type="number" id = "segments" min="3" class="form-input">
>                             <input type = "button" value = "Add Segments" onclick = "addSegment"><br>             <!--Segment Info Start-->   
>           <label for="segment">Segment Type</label>
>           <select id="segment" name="segment" class="form-input">
>               <option value="ramp">Ramp</option>
>               <option value="dwell">Dwell</option>
>               <option value="step">Step</option>
>           </select>
>
>           <label for="temp">Temperature</label>  
>           <input type="number" id = "temp" class="form-input" min="30">
>
>           <label for="time">Time</label>  
>           <input type="number" id = "time" class="form-input" min="1">            <!--Segment Info End-->     
>           <input type="reset" value="Reset"> 
>           <input type="submit" value="Start">
>        </form>
> ```

My Javascript

```
function addSegment(){

        var segments = document.getElementById("segments").value;

        var seg = segments-1;

        var i;

        for (i = 0, i<seg, i++){




        }


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamicly create html elements and append them to form. You can append them on end of form of before/after some child element in form

This is how you can append them to the end of form

```
function addSegment(){

        var segments = document.getElementById("segments").value;

        var seg = segments-1;

        var i;

        for (i = 0, i<seg, i++){
            const label = document.createElement('label');
            label.for=`someName${i}`;
            const input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type="text" // or any other
            input.name = `someName${i}`;
            // and all other attributtes you need to set
            document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(label)
            document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(input)

        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a go. Is there an easier way just by duplicating the existing created form?

Comment: You alse had errors in for loop, it uses ";" betwen instead of ","